# Hi, Just Want to Know What This Error Means

Tags: c++, visual-c++

"error C2660: 'storeInitialValues' : function does not take 1 arguments" shows up in the log of my code when I try to build. I've looked at some past errors posted here and I think it might be some kind of initialization error with either/all the usersize, v, dsize, and/or asize. I just want to see the error on the specific calling of storeInitialValues(usersize, v, dsize, asize); that's it. Thank you very much in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib> 
using namespace std;

struct vec
{

};

struct arr
{

};

void fillArray(int A[], int size);
void storeInitialValues(int * & arr, int & asize, int & dsize, vector<int>& v, int & usersize);


int main()
{
    int usersize, dsize, asize;
    vector <int> v;
    int * ptr = new int[10];
    cout << "How many values in data structures? Please enter values greater than 20." << endl;
    cin >> usersize;
    while (usersize < 21)
    {
        cout << "Error, enter values greater than 20!" << endl;
        cin >> usersize;
    }
    cout << "Alright, here are your numbers: " << endl;
    storeInitialValues(usersize, v, dsize, asize);

}

// fillArray stores sequential, unique, integer values into an array and 
//   then randomizes their order
void fillArray(int A[], int size)
{
    srand((int)time(0));
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        A[i] = i + 1;
    }
    for (int k = size - 1; k>1; k--)
    {
        swap(A[k], A[rand() % k]);
    }
}

// storeInitialValues calls fillArray to produce an array of unique randomly
//   organized values and then inserts those values into a dynamically sized
//   array and a vector.
void storeInitialValues(int * & arr, int & asize, int & dsize, vector<int>& v, int usersize)
{
    int * temp = new int[usersize];         // temporary array for randomized data
    fillArray(temp, usersize);              // get data
    for (int i = 0; i < usersize; i++)      // copy data into the dynamic data structures
    {
        add(arr, asize, dsize, temp[i]);
        v.push_back(temp[i]);
    }
    delete[] temp;                          // clean up temporary pointer
    temp = NULL;
}

void add(int & usersize, int & arr, int & dsize, int & temp[i])
{

}

void remove()
{

}
```

Comment: Looks like that function takes 5 parameters, but you're calling it with only 4 parameters.  Also, you have vector, but for some odd reason, you don't use it for the things it was meant to be used for.  Things like `int *temp = new int[usersize];` could be simply replaced with `std::vector<int> temp(usersize);`

Comment: storeInitialValues function takes 5 argument you havepassed only 4.Also the function definition with first argument as *& looks wrong. Define the input as * and pass the address.

Comment: Please write what your problem is on the title specifically.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing about your call to storeInitialValues matches the declaration.  I think you might be confused thinking the names of the variables are important.  That's not the case.  You have to pass variables that match the type of the variables in the function declaration in the correct order, the name are irrelevant.

int * & arr is a very strange declaration.  int *arr would be a pointer to an int that you could treat as an array. What exactly are you aiming for with int * &?  Mixing * and & requires that you be very careful with your usage.  But you are also using vector, which is a very safe way of dealing with arrays.  Why not just use vectors?  You also declare and allocate ptr in the main function but you don't use it nor do you delete it.